# MPAndroidChart: Different xValues for each zoom level

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

Consider a Chart with years as xValues. I want to change the xValues to months when the user zoom in or double tap. And change the xValues to days for the next zooming level.
Is it possible with great MPAndroidChart?

Comment: Yes, I think you can change the xvalues and yvalues accordingly and redraw the graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
xl.setValueFormatter(new XAxisValueFormatter() {
    @Override
    public String getXValue(String original, int index, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
        int months= index/30, days= index%30;
        if (days==0) return String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%d months", months);
        return String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%s%s",
        months == 0 ? "" : String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%d months and ", months),
        String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%d days", days));
    }
});

@Override
public void onChartScale(MotionEvent me, float scaleX, float scaleY) {
    int nLabelsToSkip= Math.min(30, Math.max((int) (120 / mChart.getViewPortHandler().getScaleX()), 0));
    nLabelsToSkip = (nLabelsToSkip/5) * 5 -1; // (n+1) should be dividable by 5        
    mChart.getXAxis().setLabelsToSkip(nLabelsToSkip);
}
```

Fully Zoom Out: 0 months, 1 months, 2 months, ...

Zoom Level 1: 0 months, 0 months and 15 days, 1 months, 1 months and 15 days, ...

Zoom Level 2: 0 months, 0 months and 10 days, 0 months and 20 days, 1 months, 1 months and 10 days, ...

Zoom Level 3: 0 months, 0 months and 5 days, 0 months and 10 days, 0 months and 15 days, 0 months and 20 days, 0 months and 25 days, 1 months, ...

Zoom Level n: 0 months, 0 months and 1 days, 0 months and 2 days, ...

Thanks for the great library @PhilJay.

Answer (score 1):

I would play with this function

```
float displayed = totalitemcount/30;
mChart.setScaleMinima(displayed, 1f);
```

I've this set up to show 30 values, but you can set it up to show whatever you need changing the values, and also changing the tags when the user doubletouchs the screen.

Comment: I don't think this can help me.